# Fourier Series for Rectangular Pulse Train (Natural Sampling Pulse Amplitude Modulation)

Tags: calculus, fourier-series, signal-processing

i'm trying to calculate the frequency spectrum of a signal that has been sampled using natural sampling PAM (pulse amplitude modulation). The message signal is given as $s(t)$, and the sampling signal is a rectangular pulse train with period $T_s$, height 1, and width $\tau$.

I know that the spectrum of the sampled signal will be the convolution between the transform of the pulse train and the message spectrum. However, I am having trouble deriving the correct expression for the series representation of the pulse train. Here is what I have so far:

$$h(t) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} D_n e^{jn2\pi ft}$$

Where $D_n$ is given by

$$D_n = \frac{1}{T_s} \int_{-\tau/2}^{\tau/2} e^{-jn2\pi t/T_s} \ dt$$

Integrating gives:

$$D_n = \frac{1}{T_s} \frac{-T_s}{jn2\pi} e^{-jn2\pi t/T_s} |^{\tau/2}_{-\tau/2}$$

Plugging in bounds gives:

$$D_n = \frac{1}{n\pi} (\sin(\frac{n\pi \tau}{T_s})) = \frac{\tau}{T_s}sinc(\frac{n \pi \tau}{T_s})$$

However every other solution I see online is not in this form (There is no pi term in the numerator of the sinc). Any suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: It's very common in engineering to define $sinc(x) = \sin(\pi x)/(\pi x)$